# Error when call 1 Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

My app with MainActivity have 2 button:

1) CreateSchedule : This button will open CreateActivity.

2) ViewSchedule: This button will open ViewActivity and ViewActivity contains only ListView, if i choose any item on ListView, EditActivity will be opened. My problem is : 
In method `onItemClick()`, I try to change

```
Intent intent = new Intent(EditActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CreateActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
```

but i got error

> "No enclosing instance of the type CreateActivity is accessible in
>   scope"

Why they can't call each other? Is this impossible because CreateActivity and ViewActivity is same level?  If not, please give me solution. Thank you guys so much.

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(ViewActivity.this, EditActivity.class);` use this

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), EditActivity.class));
```

It doesn't make any sense your first line, you want to start the same activity you are already on.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call CreateActivity as nested class, but don't declare it as `static` class. So, declare CreateActivity as `static` class or create it in a new java file as a normal class. Don't forget to declare it in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

try:
Intent intent = new Intent(ViewActivity.this, EditActivity.class);